# Weird symbols while trying to install a package in PyCharm project

Tags: python, pycharm, python-poetry

The error appears when I try to install any package with command: "poetry add " or manually "File -> Settings -> Project -> + in the corner -> search package -> press "install" button"
I have the project named "example-ed-tech" in university and poetry base interpreter of version 3.10.5

I've tried terminal commands and manual installation.
Probably, there's some problem with encoding?

Traceback:

> traceback: "‘ЁбвҐ¬Ґ ­Ґ г¤ Ґвбп ­ ©вЁ гЄ § ­­л© Їгвм. Command C:\Users\xc8\xe3\xee\xf0\xfc.pyenv\pyenv-win\versions\3.10.5\python.exe -c "import sys; print('.'.join([str(s) for s in sys.version_info[:3]]))" errored with the following return code 1, and output:"

Error screenshot
[image]

Comment: It would be helpful to get the output as text rather than an image. Most likely there is a mismatch between the encoding of the bytes being output and the terminal's encoding.

Comment: Sure! Here is the traceback:
"‘ЁбвҐ¬Ґ ­Ґ г¤ Ґвбп ­ ©вЁ гЄ § ­­л© Їгвм.

Command C:\Users\\xc8\xe3\xee\xf0\xfc\.pyenv\pyenv-win\versions\3.10.5\python.exe -c "import sys; print('.'.join([str(s) for s in sys.version_info[:3]]))" errored with the following return code 1, and output:"

Comment: `'‘ЁбвҐ¬Ґ \xadҐ г¤ Ґвбп \xad ©вЁ гЄ § \xad\xadл© Їгвм'.encode('cp1251').decode('cp866')` -> 'Системе не уд ется н йти ук з нный путь' ("The system cannot find the specified path").  So output is being encoded as cp866 but decoded as cp1251. (Unfortunately I use neither PyCharm nor Windows, so that's all the help I can provide).